# Alljoyn c# implementation for Windows 8

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi2, alljoyn

I've been playing with my Raspberry pi 2 with Windows 10 IoT. And want to send commands to device using alljoyn.

However I was unable to find any kind of client/router sample c# code.
Microsoft offers Windows.Devices.AllJoyn namespace only for Windows 10 :(
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.alljoyn.aspx

Am I the only person who want to use alljoyn in c# app other than in Windows 10?

Comment: The samples are in Windows Universal. Surely that means that it should run on Windows 10 IOT. https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AllJoyn

Comment: @Aron, thank you for reply. Probably my question was not clear enought. I have Alljoyn app on raspberry pi, but how do I connect to alljoyn bus from regular WIn8 PC. As far as I can see there is no c# implementation I can use in Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

I've started a C# wrapper project here: https://github.com/dotMorten/AllJoynDotNet

Currently supports Windows Desktop, Windows 10, and Xamarin Android, but I don't see why a Windows 8.1 Store app wouldn't be possible as well - we just need the alljoyn_c.dll compiled for 8.1.